# It's clobbering time

Tags: meaning

Is the expression "It's clobbering time" synonymous with "It is wasting my time."? Or does it carry any additional meaning?

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cps4eeCh_II):

[image]

Comment: It's time *to [clobber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering)* Frogatto: to kill him. The "Boss" tells his servant to get out of his way, because he's going to "clobber" Frogatto.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks! Good thing I haven't tried to use the expression before asking here.

Comment: You're welcome! I should've hyperlinked to a more generic definition of "**[clobber](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clobber)**" though. (0:

Comment: Emphasis on CLOB:  *It's CLOBbering time*  rather than *It's clobbering TIME*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means "it is time (for me) to clobber (things)". As mkennedy says, this is a reference to the [comic book character *The Thing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_%28comics%29).

The connotation is that "clobbering time" happens often or habitually, like "breakfast time" or "nap time", because the character is a violent person who enjoys clobbering things.

Answer (score 10):

"It's clobbering time" probably was coined by Stan Lee for his and Jack Kirby's character the Thing. The Thing is the superhero code name of Ben Grimm. Ben is a pilot and the friend of Reed Richards, scientist and inventor. Ben pilots a rocket ship out of the earth's atmosphere where the occupants are bombarded with cosmic rays, turning them into mutants. In Ben's case, he becomes a giant, knobby, super-strong monster.

The rocket ship crew becomes the Fantastic Four. One of the Thing's phrases is, "it's clobbering time." That is, time to beat up the bad guys.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it meant something around the lines of "it is beating up my time" :)

Comment: Wondering which comes first, the game in the screenshot or the Thing by Stan Lee?

Comment: Considering that issue one of Fantastic Four came out in 1961...

Answer (score 1):

"Clobbering" is functioning as an adjective in this particular sense, not as a verb that is acting on the noun.

Now is the time. What kind of time is it? "It's clobbering time!"